# ListView in Tab Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to put a custom listview in a tabbed fragment, the closest I got to is that I put it into the left "list" pane of my dual-pane activity.

Here's the problem.
I feel like something is wrong in my custom adapter and I'm not referring to context correctly. As for the tab1fragment, I'm pretty sure I'm passing that view incorrectly.
As a note, instead of populating mylistview on OnCreate I put my listView in onAttached; I've heard that that's better to avoid certain functions returning null during the create process.

The design of this application is...

Single Activity Single Pane - > Multi-Pane Activity...

Multi-Pane Activity -> Left, a small container for a fragment that will contain a listview and a few textboxes. 
[Let's call this listView A for now.]

Multi-Pane Activity - > Right,Detail Pane:
In the detail pane is a fragment that hosts tabs, each tab is a fragment. I want to put a listView in each tab.  [List view B for now?]

When trying the closest I got was sticking it in my first "listview A".

In order of brevity I chopped down I'm cutting down the code if you feel like you need more don't hesitate to ask. [Otherwise it's about 7-8 pages] I put comments specifying the code that I think is problematic. I don't fully understand my getView in my listAdapter specifically the `if (convertView == null)` code block.

If you see any other weird issues and would like to offer constructive criticism I'm totally dying for a code review!

Other things to note:
Using the fragmentsupport manager on all my code.

### Tab1DrinkFragment

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);

        ArrayList<Item> menu = new ArrayList<Item>();

        Item item1 = new Item("Coke","Pure cane sugar!", 2.50);
        Item item2 = new Item("Dr Pepper","Pure cane sugar!", 3.00);
        Item item3 = new Item("Sprite","Pure cane sugar!", 2.50);

        menu.add(item1);
        menu.add(item2);
        menu.add(item3);

        View v = getView();
        CustomOrderListAdapter adapter = new CustomOrderListAdapter(getActivity(),menu);

        ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkList); //Problem code
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

### Tab1Drink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <!-- When I got this to work I was not using @id/drinkList but @+id/android:list -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drinkList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### CustomOrderListAdapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.landa.backend.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.landa.R;

public class CustomOrderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        private ArrayList<Item> listData; //Once we get json working be a REALLY good idea to actually use the generic features of this

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public CustomOrderListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> listData) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listData = listData;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            OrderHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); //Problem code
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_order_list_row, null);
                holder = new OrderHolder();
                holder.nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                holder.priceView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                holder.removedItemsView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.removedItems);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (OrderHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Item item = (Item)listData.get(position);
            holder.nameView.setText(item.getName());
            holder.priceView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
            //holder.removedItemsView.setText(Arrays.toString(item.getRemoved()));

            return convertView;
        }

        static class OrderHolder {
            TextView nameView;
            TextView priceView;
            TextView removedItemsView;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ArrayList<Item> menu = new ArrayList<Item>();

    Item item1 = new Item("Coke","Pure cane sugar!", 2.50);
    Item item2 = new Item("Dr Pepper","Pure cane sugar!", 3.00);
    Item item3 = new Item("Sprite","Pure cane sugar!", 2.50);

    menu.add(item1);
    menu.add(item2);
    menu.add(item3);

    CustomOrderListAdapter adapter = new CustomOrderListAdapter(getActivity(),menu);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Tab1Drink, null);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drinkList); //Problem code
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: So I'm guessing it's better to put it in onCreateView than onAttach?

Comment: I havent looked at the source, but im not even sure if there is a valid view if you don't return one from the onCreateView. But yes, this is the appropriate place construct your views. onAttachView could get called multiple times as you and and remove your fragment, the onCreateView should only be called once.

Comment: I do return a view from onCreate, I just didn't show my onCreate. I'm confused on saving that - is it implicitly saved if I just create a View view field in my class? Some of the structure of android still feels hocus pocus to me.

Comment: Im confused by your question, what do you mean is it saved?